# Is there a way to dynamically change relational operators (<, >, ==, etc.)?

Tags: matlab

For instance, consider the following code:

```
myLogicalsVariable = ...
    myMatrix1 == myValue1 & ... 
    myMatrix2 == myValue2 & ...
    myMatrix3 == myValue3 & ...
    myMatrix4 == myValue4 & ...
    myMatrix5 == myValue5;
```

Is there any way to make the `relational operators` in this statement dynamic somehow such that I'd end up with something like:

```
myLogicalsVariable = ...
    myMatrix1 RelationalOp1 myValue1 & ... 
    myMatrix2 RelationalOp2 myValue2 & ...
    myMatrix3 RelationalOp3 myValue3 & ...
    myMatrix4 RelationalOp4 myValue4 & ...
    myMatrix5 RelationalOp5 myValue5;
```

where each `RelationalOp` variable could be assigned one of the operators (`==`, `<`, `<=`, etc.)?

I know I can accomplish this with the `eval` function by doing something like this:

```
myLogicalsVariable = ...
    eval(['myMatrix1 ' RelationalOp1 ' myValue1 &' ... 
          'myMatrix2 ' RelationalOp2 ' myValue2 &' ...
          'myMatrix3 ' RelationalOp3 ' myValue3 &' ...
          'myMatrix4 ' RelationalOp4 ' myValue4 &' ...
          'myMatrix5 ' RelationalOp5 ' myValue5']);
```

and passing the `relational operators` as strings in each of the `RelationalOp` variables.

I was wondering if there is an alternative way to accomplish this?  The `eval` function is a bit slow...

Comment: Why can't you change the syntax `myMatrix1 RelationalOp1 myValue1` to `RelationalOp1(myMatrix1,myValue1)`? In that case you'd only need to define `RelationalOp1` as an ordinary two-variable function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the Matlab rational operators can be used like regular functions, so you can replace, for example, `A<B` with `lt(A,B)` (see [here](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/relational-operators.html) for the full list). You could possibly do something like the following:

```
relop=@(A,B,op) op(A,B);
```

which defines a function that applies relational operator `op` to `A` and `B`.

Then you could do this:

```
myLogicalsVariable = relop(myMatrix1,myValue1,@eq) & relop(myMatrix2,myValue2,@eq);
```

To dynamically change the operation, you could define a variable, `RelationalOp1=@lt`, for example, then do

```
myLogicalsVariable = relop(myMatrix1,myValue1,relationalOp1) ...
    & relop(myMatrix2,myValue2,relationOp2);
```

Comment: A function handle is the solution, but what good is `relop`?  You can just write `relationalOp1(myMatrix1, myValue1) & relationOp2(myMatrix2, myValue2)`